# How can I trace the macOS network stack?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, safari, firewall

In safari, and several other products, I get a network timeout where I have to reload the page, even though I have a full / working Wifi connection.

This is a sporadic issue.

The problem seems to occur after I installed Cisco's security product "OpenDNS Umbrella".  Removing OpenDNS Umbrella seems to fix the problem.

I would like to get a better understanding of the network layers in macOS so I can create an appropriate trace/diagnostic for review.

1. What are the "layers" of software that are available for extension and modification in macOS?  (I'm from a Windows Mindset and understand MSFT's well-documented network API, packet filters, and what extensions are available etc).
2. How can I create a trace of network activity at the aforementioned layers? For example, I want to see not just DNS traces, but any internal firewall that could be affecting me?  (macOS has a built-in firewall that might be giving me trouble.)

I did briefly install "Little Snitch" firewall program, but I then uninstalled it.  I'm not sure if this is relevant, but it does manage connections via an API I'm not aware of.

Comment: System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall. If it's off there, there is no firewall (from a built-into-macOS perspective) active.

Comment: @tubedogg - the Gui firewall is off.  Issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Wireshark.  Maybe monitoring the actual network activity will give you a clue (it will probably show an outgoing packet or connection that isn't answered).