# How does WireShark work on OS X? What processes does it interact with?

Tags: macos, network, tcp, wireshark

I'm looking for deep/detailed research into how the MacOS TCP stack works. Namely, what are the files/Dynamic Libraries that offer this service?

What Libraries does WireShark interact with?

My goal is to trace a logical chain of drivers, processes, and configurations that enable a TCP connection to work.

I'll inspect the version of the files, their corresponding default settings, and anything else that can influence their behavior.

My goal is to [diagnose the issue described](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/255835/1337) in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark uses the /dev/bpf* devices.

From the Wireshark install readme.txt (describing system modifications):

> /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.wireshark.ChmodBPF.plist. A launch daemon that adjusts permissions on the system's packet capture devices (/dev/bpf*) when the system starts up.

The bpfx devices are mechanisms designed to inspect network traffic (i.e. exactly the use case for WireShark).

Or as [man bpf](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=bpf) says:

> The Berkeley Packet Filter provides a raw interface to data link layers in a protocol independent fashion. All packets on the network, even those destined for other hosts, are accessible through this mechanism.
>
> The packet filter appears as a character special device, /dev/bpf. After opening the device, the file descriptor must be bound to a specific network interface with the BIOCSETIF ioctl. A given interface can be shared by multiple listeners, and the filter underlying each descriptor will see an identical packet stream.